# Focus an item if up and down is being pressed while inside input field

Tags: javascript, html

How can I move up and down and focus an item if an up arrow key or down arrow key is being pressed? I need to do this in pure javascript.

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="item" onclick="ItemOnClick('10000001')" onkeypress="ItemOnClick('10000001')">How are you?</div>
    <div class="item" onclick="ItemOnClick('10000002')" onkeypress="ItemOnClick('10000002')">What's your name?</div>
    <div class="item" onclick="ItemOnClick('10000003')" onkeypress="ItemOnClick('10000003')">Are you fine?</div>
</div>
<input autocomplete=off id=input onkeyup="InputOnKeyUp(this);" type=search>
<script>
function InputOnKeyUp(Input) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        // move up to focus an item from list
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        // move down to focus an item from list
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: u should consider adding a css class so inside the if clauses u can add or strip the item of the class

Comment: Give them a `tabindex` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex and use tabulator.

Comment: @Lain It's only limited with tabs, isn't it?

Comment: @JustInTime: Yes. Usually tab is tabbing (what you are trying to do) and arrow keys are scrolling. You can not focus `div` without a `tabindex`tho.

Comment: @Ayoub Benchaliah: What purpose would a css class serve here?

Comment: @JavaScript  CSS :focus Selector could be used with JS to do the trick

Comment: @Ayoub Benchaliah: No, css does not provide any support here, unless you want to style the Elements differently. Yet this does not seem to be the question/issue here. Even if, you could style them without a class using #list > :focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to give the elements a `tabindex`to allow `div` to get focused. Also the keyup on the `input#input` is silly since you always lose the focus by focusing a list-element anyway - so just put the keyup on the `#list` itself.

### Edit:

To prevent scrolling you can change `onkeyup` to `onkeydown`.

```js
function ItemOnClick(number){console.log(number)}

function InputOnKeyUp(input){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

    var tList = document.querySelector('#list'),
        tNodes = tList.children,
        tIndex = ~~tList.getAttribute('data-tabindex');

    if(event.keyCode == 38){
        tIndex -= 1
        // move up to focus an item from list
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 40){
        tIndex += 1
        // move down to focus an item from list
    };
    
    if(tIndex >= tNodes.length){
        tIndex = 0 //REM: We select the first item 
    };
    
    if(tIndex < 0){
        tIndex = tNodes.length -1 //REM: We select the last item
    };

    if(tNodes[tIndex]){
        tNodes[tIndex].focus(); //REM: Focusing the element
        tList.setAttribute('data-tabindex', tIndex) //REM: Storing the selected item
    }
};

//REM: Focus the first item
document.querySelector('#list').children[0].focus();
```

```html
<!-- Give the items a tabindex to allow them to get focused. Also enables tab and shift+tab.
Also we move the keyup to the #list. Else the input keeps losing focus. -->
<div id="list" onkeydown="InputOnKeyUp(this);">
    <div class="item" onclick="ItemOnClick('10000001')" onkeypress="ItemOnClick('10000001')" tabindex = '1'>How are you?</div>
    <div class="item" onclick="ItemOnClick('10000002')" onkeypress="ItemOnClick('10000002')" tabindex = '2'>What's your name?</div>
    <div class="item" onclick="ItemOnClick('10000003')" onkeypress="ItemOnClick('10000003')" tabindex = '3'>Are you fine?</div>
</div>
<!--
<input autocomplete=off id=input " type=search onkeyup="InputOnKeyUp(this);>
-->
```

Comment: Thank you, though this doesn't directly solve the problem but the sense are right there. I just need to modify my code and apply this `data-tabindex`.